# Accidentally deleted remote branch from home computer

Tags: git, github

I am kind of new to git and I accidentally deleted a remote branch from my home computer.
Would the data still be there at my working computer?
My hope is that it should have the data in local, but I just want to re-confirm.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what it is you actually did; i.e. which commands did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the local branch should be unaffected by this.  If you have not pushed anything to the remote since the last time you pulled to your working computer, then your local copy is up to date.  You can try pushing this branch out to the remote via:

```
git push -u origin branch_you_accidentally_deleted
```

To reiterate, this solution assumes that you do not have any *new* changes in the deleted remote which your working computer does *not* have.  If this not be the case, then your other option is to undo the delete on GitHub to try to recover the deleted new commits.

Comment: @q_kim Please review this answer if you get a chance, thanks.